# Programmatically create a GridView with full screen items

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I need to create a horizontal list view for a Windows Store application with full screen image items, something like the Gallery control for Android. To do this, I've used a `GridView` and changed the `ItemsPanel` template to be a `VirtualizingStackPanel` with horizontal orientation. The problem is that I cannot make the Image items to be full screen. What I've tried is to make the `GridView.ItemContainerStyle` to bind to the `GridView`'s width, like this:

```
Binding widthBinding = new Binding() { Source=iconsHolder, Path = new PropertyPath("Width"), Converter = new TestItemWidthConverter()};

Style itemStyle  = new Style();
itemStyle.TargetType = typeof(GridViewItem);
itemStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(GridViewItem.WidthProperty, widthBinding));// 800));

iconsHolder.ItemContainerStyle = itemStyle;
```

When I replace the `widthBinding` with 800, for example, the icons have the specified width, but when I use the binding, no items are visible, so the `Style` do its job, but the `Binding` has a problem. In order to debug this, I've created a fake converter, so I can see if the binding works, but the Convert(..) method isn't called at all.

My GridView is created like this:

```
GridView iconsHolder = new GridView();
iconsHolder.ItemsPanel = App.Current.Resources["HorizontalVSPTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
iconsHolder.ItemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["MyDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
iconsHolder.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
iconsHolder.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
```

and my resources are defined like:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalVSPTemplate">
   <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
   <Image Source="some irrelevant url here"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

My converter looks like this:

```
public sealed class TestItemWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine(" binding width=" + value);
      return value;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
   { return value; }
}
```

I don't know how to achieve this (I've also tried using `RelativeBinding` or make Icons to be horizontally stretched, without success) or what I'm doing wrong, so please help!
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure it out that I was on the wrong path, the right way to do it was to use `FlipView`, just as simple as

```
FlipView iconsHolder = new FlipView();
iconsHolder.ItemsSource =  myItems;
iconsHolder.ItemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["MyDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

Now my icons are full screen by default and the scroll effect is paged. Some useful details about this control can be found here: [Quickstart: Adding FlipView controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781233.aspx) .